# System.Linq Expressions evaluating true on a single entity

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to DRY out some lambda expressions for security rights. Is it possible to take a lamda expression and apply it to a single entity for true?

Like lets say I have a Person and a DocumentFolder

```
    Expression<Func<Person, bool>> CanSeePerson()
    {
        return c =>  !c.IsPrivate;
    }
```

And one for the folder

```
    Expression<Func<DocumentFolder, bool>> CanSeeFolder()
    {
        return c => !c.IsPrivate && c.Owner.CanSeePerson(); // <- ???
    }
```

How the heck can I use that CanSeePerson() function  on a single type to return true and maintain an expression that can be used in linq queries like such

```
Entities.DocumentFolder.Where(CanSeeFolder());
```

I know how to use the where on an iqueryable but I can't see how to apply the expression tree to a single value.

---

This throws the error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Person'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

```
Expression<Func<DocumentFolder, bool>> CanSeeFolder()
    {
        return c => !c.IsPrivate &&_entities.Persons.Where(x => x.Id == c.Owner.Id).Any(CanSeePerson());
}
```

---

The difference seems to be based on putting the IQueryable Directly in the statement. This also does NOT work

```
Expression<Func<DocumentFolder, bool>> CanSeeFolder()
    {
        return c => !c.IsPrivate &&_entities.Persons.Where(CanSeePerson()).Contains(c.User);
    }
```

but this DOES work

```
Expression<Func<DocumentFolder, bool>> CanSeeFolder()
        {
            var canSeePersons = _entities.Persons.Where(CanSeePerson());
            return c => !c.IsPrivate && canSeePersons.Contains(c.User);
        }
```

p.s. I know I suck @ using this stackoverflow formatting thing lol

---

The reason why this works is because the CanSeePerson() function cannot be converted and used in an expression. When you put the canSeePersons variable in the function instead you are placing in an iQueryable type which can be used in an expression. Using "var" convolutes it a bit.

Comment: I'm probably missing something simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` that solves your problem. The trick is to simply transform your list of objects to the list you want to filter. It is not always possible, but many times it is. You just have to be a bit creative :-)

When using extension methods you can easily come up with a solution that allows you to do this:

```
var visibleFolders = Entities.DocumentFolder.WhereCanSeeFolder();
```

Here is the (completely DRY) solution:

```
public static class SecurityExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<DocumentFolder> WhereCanSeeFolder(
        this IQueryable<DocumentFolder> folders)
    {
        var visibleOwners = folders.Select(f => f.Owner)
            .Where(CanSeePerson);

        return
            from folder in folders.Where(CanSeeFolder)
            where visibleOwners.Contains(folder.Owner)
            select folder;
    }

    private static readonly Expression<Func<DocumentFolder, bool>>
        CanSeeFolder = folder => !folder.IsPrivate;

    private static readonly Expression<Func<Person, bool>>
        CanSeePerson = person => !person.IsPrivate;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I see where you're going with this. The reason why I did it with the Expression<Func<Person>> is so that I can reuse it on another piece of code (DRY) like on a Picture.Owner or a Notes.Owner. I don't want to have to repeat the same query for each seperate class. I want to reuse the Expression on each Person

Comment: The reason why I don't want to repeat it is because the Expressions will be much more complicated then this

Comment: @Kyle: I updated my answer. Look closely at my code and how I transform the list of `DocumentFolder` objects to a filtered list of `Person` objects and use that in a `where Contains`. I think this effectively solves your problem and keeps your code as DRY as a desert.

Comment: This does work! Thanks, now I have to figure out why this works and the other one doesn't. Thanks a lot

Comment: Whoehaahaha, I have finally beaten the famous Jon Skeet AND the great Marc Gravell at the same time :-D

Answer (score 2):

The expression tree *is* only applied to a single value at a time, logically, within the LINQ expression.

If you're saying you want to apply it *in-process* later to a single value, you can just use:

```
// This can be cached
Func<DocumentFolder, bool> canSeeFolderDelegate = CanSeeFolder().Compile();

DocumentFolder folder = ...; // Get the value from somewhere
if (canSeeFolderDelegate(folder))
{
    // Yes, you can see that folder
}
```

Comment: If you compile it then it's no longer an expression

Comment: @Kyle: Sure, but you're just trying to evaluate it locally, right? You can keep the expression and compile it when you need to, if you want. What benefit do you think there is to keeping it *only* as an expression? Given you comments to Marc's answer, it sounds like you've got some requirements you haven't told us about. Basically, you need to give us *much* more context.

Comment: I guess I dropped the clarity ball, definetly isint the first time. My apologies. Yes it must remain as an expression so that I can send it to the database using entity framework 4

Comment: @Kyle: How were you planning to "send it to the database" in the first place?

Comment: using ef4 with a statement similar to Entities.DocumentFolder.Where(CanSeeFolder());

Comment: @Kyle: But `Where` is always applied to a sequence, isn't it? What is `Entities.DocumentFolder` here - something you've already fetched? Or an `IQueryable<DocumentFolder>`?

Comment: That would be an IQueryable<DocumentFolder>

Comment: @Kyle: Okay, so that's already going to be applying it to a sequence of elements, which isn't what you want, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you want to *evaluate* it for a single entity?

```
var func = CanSeeFolder().Compile(); // <=== store and re-use this;
                                     //      this isn't free
bool canSee = func(obj);
```

Another approach might be:

```
bool canSee = Enumerable.Repeat(obj, 1).AsQueryable().Any(CanSeeFolder());
```

but this is *probably* still going to do the `Compile` somewhere in the chain, so you may as well use the more direct code (at the top).

---

Edit re comments:

To evaluate that *at the database*, you would need a restriction, for example:

```
bool canSee = db.Folders.Where(f => f.FolderId == id)
                .Where(CanSeeFolder()).Any();
```

which limits us to the single row, then adds your extra filter.

Comment: can't compile it because then you wouldn't be able to transport it to the db as an expression

Comment: @Kyle - you didn't say it *had* to evaluate at the DB... I'll add a (second) update...

Comment: I actually tried something like that and I got an error like this

Comment: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Person'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: @Kyle - I can't comment on that without seeing the code you are using to *do* that. The `Where` approach on a primary-key doesn't use the `Expression.Constant` approach, so should be fine.

Comment: I was hoping I was missing a feature of expressions that allowed you to apply it to a single object